# Difficulty in finding data anomalies

Tags: php, mysql, database, algorithm, statistics

I'm working on an analytical statistics project. My data is thousands of daily transactions and by daily matter, I want to flag transactions under certain scenarios.

The problem comes from the fact that there are 5 parameters that by them I'm grouping data.

The scenarios I'm flagging are always from comparing the current daily transaction with the large recent group. A scenario could be if the price is 3 times larger than the group's average, or if the number of transactions this month has doubled.

For example:

I have 1000 transactions today. The 5 flags which I group them by are:

1.Time(Day/Night)

2.Currency(USD/EUR)

3.Gender

4.Paid full price or not

5.Country

In that example 4 out of 5 flags are binary, but the country list has many more options.

In reality in my case, the number of groups I'm more likely to have should be closer to 1000.

So if I have 700 groups I want to compare against. I need to query data of at least 500 transactions per group.

Should I pinpoint for 700 cases the data I need in my query?

where (a=1 and b=0 ... e=10) or (a=0 and b=0 ... e=30) or .... or (a=0 and b=1 ... e=30) => 700 cases.

Should I query a lot of data that I don't need and in another way match my 1000 daily transactions each to their group?

Is there another way it can be done?

Cheers

Comment: What is stopping you from choosing one solution over the other? Are you concerned about performance? maintainability? scalability? flexibility? If performance is the concern then the only answer is **go benchmark your code and make a decision**.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
It appears that you have yet to do some expected research on the topic, to have a question focused enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why can't you generate a hash of all your scenario, add that as a column to your records and group by that?